M2E Pro eBay product not visible after refund
a customer of mine has a problem with his Magento2 store and the connected eBay account.
He created multiple products under a specific category and sold them over the M2E Pro extension at eBay. After some days, the clients of him asked for a refund and he proceeded over eBay with the refund.
After the refunding process, the product is back in stock at the Magento2 store, but is not relisted in elasticsearch.
The problem occurs only in some categories, the client said. Also he mentioned, that it changed after the last Magento2 update the agency before has made.
I already talked to M2E Pro, they said, that it is not a problem with the extension as it works fine and we can see that in the admin dashboard too. Everything seems to be fine with the product state so the product has to be in elasticsearch.
Do you have some thoughts about my problem? We are using Magento2 Ver.-2.4.6-p2 and M2E Pro Ver.1.47.1.
Thank you for your help!
